# Is it allowed to treat sons better than daughters?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, sharia, hadith-interpretation, children

When this question is asked, [Muslim 1623](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1623f) is quoted on Islamic websites. But in the Hadith, the prophet (pbuh) only asks if the man has more sons. Does that mean it’s permissible to treat daughters differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In giving gifts to one's children it is prescribed to treat them justly, regardless of whether they are sons or daughters. The wording of the hadith is inclusive of both genders: اعدلوا بين أولادكم (be just to your children) - [Bukhari 2587](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2587)

With regards to the division between sons and daughters, there are different madhabs:

The view of the majority is that in gifts the daughters should be given a share equal to the sons.

> ساووا بين أولادكم في العطية، ولو كنت مؤثرا أحدا لآثرت النساء على الرجال
>
> Establish equality in giving gifts to your children, if I was to prefer one over the other then I would have preferred the females over the males
>
> <sup>— [Sunan Sa‘eed ibn Mansoor](https://shamela.ws/book/13122/315) and [al-Bayhaqi](https://shamela.ws/book/148486/6879) - classed by Ibn Hajar as Hasan in [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/2980)</sup>

Others held the view that the daughters should be given half the share of the sons, reflecting the distribution of inheritance in the Quran (verse  [4:11](https://quran.com/4/11?translations=20)).

---

**Ref:**

> فقال أبو يوسف من الحنفية، والمالكية والشافعية وهو رأي الجمهور: يستحب للأب أن يسوي بين الأولاد ـ الذكور والإناث ـ في العطية، فتعطى الأنثى مثلما يعطى الذكر؛ لقوله صلّى الله عليه وسلم: «سووا بين أولادكم في العطية، ولو كنت مؤثراً
> لآثرت النساء على الرجال» رواه سعيد بن منصور في سننه والبيهقي بإسناد حسن، وفي رواية للبخاري: «اتقوا الله واعدلوا بين أولادكم» ، ولأن العدل في القسمة والمعاملة مطلوب ، وقدحملوا الأمر في هذه الأحاديث على الندب.
> وقال الحنابلة، ومحمد من الحنفية: للأب أن يقسم بين أولاده على حسب قسمة الله تعالى
> في الميراث، فيجعل للذكر مثل حظ الأنثيين؛ لأن الله تعالى قسم بينهم كذلك
>
> <sup>— [Fiqh al-Islami wa Adillatuhu](https://shamela.ws/book/384/3902#p1)</sup>