Do parents need to treat their children with fairness or justness in Islam?
To start with, what I mean by fairness or justness here is meant in the context of general help and financial support etc. in an equal manner not necessarily with equal amounts.
Allah the Almighty actually prescribed for men who want to marry more than a wife to treat their wives in justness saying:

And if you fear that you will not deal justly with the orphan girls, then marry those that please you of [other] women, two or three or four. But if you fear that you will not be just, then [marry only] one or those your right hand possesses. That is more suitable that you may not incline [to injustice]. (4:3)

In my imperfection, I could not identify any Islamic religious text that prescribes equal treatment for children, that's why I'm asking whether there is any kind of prescription or at least recommendation to treat the children in such a just, equal or fair manner as meant above and as I'll try to explain by the following example:
Let's say you have more than one child who maybe intelligent, lazy or whatever attribute comes to mind, they might be sane and normal born or disabled nevertheless you'd buy them clothes and be in charge for them etc. because it is a duty especially as long as they are dependent on you, but what if they are mature maybe even married, but some are rich, some are poor and or needy or sick/disabled still dependent on your support. So can a parent for example support only the "needy" child and ignore the "rich" one?

Quran_en.sarwar.txt 4:3 words it not only as justice but also as equality, which, in English, may be very different concepts depending on the context. Unfortunately I don't understand Quranic Arab language. (Not even modern day Arabic.)

May all your children be healthy and sane, but just think of someone having a normal born child and a disabled one. What would be justice, what would be equality?

@GyroGearloose thank you for your comment. In my question I concentrated on the case that raised the question in the first place. However, your contribution shows that there are other cases that present a similar situation. I am not 100% sure what the best choice of words is, whether it is justness, equality, fairness etc., I personally think fairness describes it best.

Relevant: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/76307

As for obligatory spending then a condition of it being obligatory to support an adult is that the recipient must be in need. You should be able to find this covered under the rulings of نفقة , like https://islamqa.info/en/answers/13464
